# Redirect the user to the URL of REST API after sending the post request using Needle

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, needle.js

I am working with a REST API that as a result of a POST request to an address like `https://example.com/api` returns an HTML webpage (instead of JSON or other data formats).

Normally on the front-end side dealing with such scenario is not difficult to manage using a code like this:

```html
<form action="https://example.com/api" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="param1" value="test1">
  <input type="text" name="param2" value="test2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In that case only pressing the submit button results in loading the URL `https://example.com/api` with the right parameters. However, I am unable to replicate this on server-side code using Node js and Needle library.

I used a code snippet like this:

```
let params = {
  param1: "test1",
  param2: "test2"
};

let options = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
};

needle.post("https://example.com/api", params, options, function (err, response) {
  console.log(response.body);
  //what should i do here?
});
```

but at this point, I don't know how to redirect the client to the address. The `response.body` property contains the webpage HTML but sending it directly using:

```
res.send(response.body);
```

leads to distorted webpage appearance due to missing css files and relative URLs. Also redirecting directly to the webpage in the callback seems not to work:

```
res.redirect("https://example.com/api");
```

Comment: _"leads to distorted webpage appearance due to missing css files and relative URLs"_ - of course, all relative URLs will be resolved using _your_ page's URL as basis. _"Also redirecting directly to the webpage in the callback seems not to work"_ - that makes the client make a new GET request. So of course any POST data this URL expects will be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured that out myself, we can just use URL queries just like the GET requests:

```
res.redirect("https://example.com/api?param1=test1&param2=test2");
```